# Component Output with Promise

Tags: angular, promise, angular2-components

I have a button component which has an Event Emitter, and when it is triggered I want to start a loading animation in the button, and when the promise is resolved, stop the loading animation.

```
@Output() promiseClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

This would be used something like:

```
<my-button (promiseClick)="makeAPICall()"></my-button>
```

Where the makeAPICall() method returns a Promise.

I need the my-button component to know when the makeAPICall() promise has been resolved. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What does " to know" mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<my-button #button (promiseClick)="button.makeKnown(makeAPICall())"></my-button>
```

```
makeKnown(p:Promise) {
  p.then(result => this.result = result);
}
```

Comment: But how can I access the 'then' callback from the promise inside of the 'my-button' component? Because 'my-button' doesn't know about the makeKnown function.

Comment: Sorry had a mistake. I updated the answer. `makeKnown` would be inside `my-button`.  I don't know if this is what you want because you didn't answer the question from the comment to your answer.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want! Thanks a lot! It seems a bit haxxy though, Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: You could make `promiseClick` an `@Input()` in `<my-button>` instead of an `@Output()` and then call `this.promiseClick()` from inside `<my-button>`. Then the button knows when the promise returned. `<my-button [promiseClick]="makeApiCall">`